# Purely functional uniquely-represented deques

Tags: ds.data-structures, functional-programming

[There are a number of purely functional deques that support $O(1)$ operations at each end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271256/implement-an-immutable-deque-as-a-balanced-binary-tree/3274355#3274355). None that I know of are "uniquely represented" - deques with the same number of items can have different shapes.

In the imperative case, doubly-linked lists are uniquely represented deques with constant-time operations.

[Hoogerwoord, in "A Logarithmic Implementation of Flexible Arrays"](http://alexandria.tue.nl/repository/notdare/772185.pdf), showed that Braun trees have logarithmic deque operations, and they are purely functional and uniquely represented.

Is there a deterministic uniquely represented purely functional deque with $o(\log n)$ operations?

Comment: What are the advantages of unique representation?

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving, one advantage of a unique representation is shown in [Hartline et al.'s "Characterizing History Independent Data Structures"](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~hartline/papers/hist-indep-ISAAC-02.pdf) - they have some useful security properties.

Comment: Doubly-linked lists are only uniquely represented if one cannot compare pointers.

Comment: The same is true for Braun trees, and binary tries, of course. Nonetheless, this seems to be the terminology. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22uniquely+represented+dictionaries%22